# How can I add the date to my posts in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, momentjs, ejs

I am making a blog using JavaScript, Express, and ejs templates.  With each blog post there is the ability to post a comment, and I would like to have the date posted with each comment.  The content of the comments are values being pulled from input fields in an .ejs file.  Right now I am using moment.js, but the date/time keeps updating.  I would like it to only show the date/time the comment was created.

Here is some code from my app.js file:

```
   moment = require('moment');
   app.locals.moment = moment
```

This my route for creating the comment:

```
app.post("/comments/:id", (req, res) => {
  Blog.findById(req.params.id, (err, blog) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("BLOG", blog);
      let newComment = { comment: req.body.comment };
      Comment.create(newComment.comment, (err, comment) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Something went wrong:", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success!  Comment Posted", comment);
          comment.save();
          blog.comments.push(comment);
          blog.save();
          res.redirect("/blog/" + blog._id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And from my .ejs file:

```
<em><%= moment(Date()).format(shortDateFormat) %></em>
```

I think this should be enough to get the gist of it.  This is probably a really easy fix but I'm still a pretty green coder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a noSQL database like Mongo? I would just put the date in the schema of your blog post like so:

```
created_date: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now
}
```

then you can call it from the database and pass it down to your ejs file.

Comment: Oh that's awesome!! I didn't know I could do that.  Is there documentation for other things I can add in my schemas?  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sure thing! I use Mongoose for my mongo schemas in Node. You can see the docs here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how I can format this would you>

Comment: for the Date object, you can check it all out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

you might be able to get away using Moment.js, too...tho it might be overkill it it's the only place you'll use it.